# LibGDX - My sprite glitches when it moves

Tags: java, libgdx

My player sprite glitches when it moves across the screen. I've tried multiplying movements by delta time. I've tried rounding. It seems to do this completely at random. Sometimes I can move it all the way across the screen and its fine, other times it glitches and twitches the entire way.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //update the camera
    camera.update();

    //clear the screen with black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //update the renderer and render
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    //update players movement on x-axis and apply gravity and increase x-axis speed if the player is jumping
    if(player.movingLeft)
        player.movement[0] -= Math.round(player.playerSpeed * delta);
    if(player.movingRight)
        player.movement[0] += Math.round(player.playerSpeed * delta);
    if(player.movingUp)
        player.movement[1] += player.playerSpeed * delta;

    //handle jumping
    if(player.isJumping) {
        if(player.jumpCurrentY < player.MAX_JUMP_DURATION) {
            player.momentum = 0;
            player.jumpSpeed++;
            player.movement[1] = player.jumpSpeed;
            if (player.jumpSpeed > 5)
                player.jumpSpeed = 5;
            player.jumpCurrentY++;
        } else if(player.hangTime < player.MAX_HANG_TIME) {
            player.momentum = 0;
            player.hangTime++;
            player.movement[1] = 2.8f;
        } else {
            player.isJumping = false;
            player.jumpCurrentY = 0;
            player.hangTime = 0;
            player.jumpSpeed = 0;
            player.momentum = gravity;
        }
    } else {
        player.jumpCurrentY = 0;
    }

    updateSprite(delta, player, player.movement, collidableTiles);

    //set sprite batch projection matrix and draw to the screen
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    player.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    //reset player movement
    Arrays.fill(player.movement, 0);

    //increment player momentum by gravity and assign it to the players y-axis movement
    player.momentum += gravity;
    player.movement[1] = player.momentum;
    player.momentum += -1;
    if(player.momentum < -5)
        player.momentum = -5;

    //TEMPORARY
    camera.position.set(Math.round(player.getX()), Math.round(player.getY()), 0);


}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what this glitch looks like? The symptoms are often helpful in identifying the root cause. Without seeing an example, my best guess is [it may be due to non-integer scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35829604/3064164). You should also edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example — all the code needed to demonstrate the issue, present inside the question itself, not linked in an external site whose contents may change or go offline.

Comment: Usually it's good form to paste only the relevant code, instead of pasting the entire source code for the entire project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because you update the camera's position out of sync with the `player`'s position.

In `public void render(float delta)` in `LevelOne` you start by updating the `camera`'s transform by calling `camera.update`, but you really want to do this **after** you've calculated the new position of the player.

If you change around your code to first calculate the new positions of the player, then call the `updateSprite` method and then call `camera.update` the glitching will go away.

Or in code, change your `LevelOne` `render` method to:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    //clear the screen with black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //update players movement on x-axis and apply gravity and increase x-axis speed if the player is jumping
    if(player.movingLeft)
        player.movement[0] -= Math.round(player.playerSpeed * delta);
    if(player.movingRight)
        player.movement[0] += Math.round(player.playerSpeed * delta);
    if(player.movingUp)
        player.movement[1] += player.playerSpeed * delta;

    //handle jumping
    if(player.isJumping) {
        if(player.jumpCurrentY < player.MAX_JUMP_DURATION) {
            player.momentum = 0;
            player.jumpSpeed++;
            player.movement[1] = player.jumpSpeed;
            if (player.jumpSpeed > 5)
                player.jumpSpeed = 5;
            player.jumpCurrentY++;
        } else if(player.hangTime < player.MAX_HANG_TIME) {
            player.momentum = 0;
            player.hangTime++;
            player.movement[1] = 2.8f;
        } else {
            player.isJumping = false;
            player.jumpCurrentY = 0;
            player.hangTime = 0;
            player.jumpSpeed = 0;
            player.momentum = gravity;
        }
    } else {
        player.jumpCurrentY = 0;
    }


    updateSprite(delta, player, player.movement, collidableTiles);
    //TEMPORARY
    camera.position.set(Math.round(player.getX()), Math.round(player.getY()), 0);
    //update the camera
    camera.update();


    //update the renderer and render
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();


    //set sprite batch projection matrix and draw to the screen
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    player.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    //reset player movement
    Arrays.fill(player.movement, 0);

    //increment player momentum by gravity and assign it to the players y-axis movement
    player.momentum += gravity;
    player.movement[1] = player.momentum;
    player.momentum += -1;
    if(player.momentum < -5)
        player.momentum = -5;
}
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you for helping!!

Comment: Glad it helped, @DawnShard. It is sometimes helpful to think of the gameloop as something that does two distinct things; update the state (positions) and render. Usually it is easier to keep those separate so that they don't overlap.